# replace string into bracket in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying this

```
str = "@a@b";
str2 = str.replace(/@/g,'-[' + str + ']');
```

output should be
-[a]-[b]

Comment: wouldn't it be better to, instead, split on `'@'`, remove the first element (which will be empty), wrap each element in `'['` and `']'` and then join on `'-'`?

Comment: can you define the formula? what happens when `str = @@a@bc`?

Comment: If you don't really need a more complex pattern recognition than a single char, using a regex will maybe over-complexify things. regexes are not magic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could search for `@` and not `@` as following, then replace the group.

```
/@([^@]+)/g
 @           look for this character literately
  (     )    group, this is the part used for replacing -> $1 in replacement string
   [^@]+     look for one or more not @ characters
          g  global flag, replace all found matches
```

The replacement is made with the first group `$1`.

```js
var str = "@a@b",
    str2 = str.replace(/@([^@]+)/g,'-[$1]');

console.log(str2);
```

Comment: can you explain about your regex symbol?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this and replace with group 1 `-[$1]`

```js
var str = "@a@b";
var str2 = str.replace(/@(.)/g, '-[$1]');
console.log(str2);
```

[`@(.)`](https://regex101.com/r/RvBXvw/1)

Comment: If it is guaranteed that only one character follows a `@` this would work as it only selects the first character after each `@`: `@axy@bz` gives `-[a]xy-[b]z`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description) function

```js
var str = "@a@b";
console.log( str.replace(/@\w/g, m => "[" + m.substring(1) + "]") );
```